# AngularJS single selection filter does not work

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I've got code for multiple selection filter and it does work, but I would like to be able to select just one value. Removing "multiple" does not work.

```js
<ui-select multiple ng-model="vm.reportfilters.titles" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;" title="Choose a person">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a value in the list">{{$item.value}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="title in vm.titles | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="title.value"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: please post controller code

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?